# Getting tweets with current hashtag from Twitter using Python?

Tags: python, twitter, tweets

Is there any better way to get tweets from twitter then crawling twitter.com and mutating URLs?

If there is, how can I get latest tweets with current hash-tag?

Thank you!

Comment: What is *current* hashtag?

Comment: @alko for instance: Google

Comment: As my answer is accepted, is seems that my guess was right. The thing I was not sure of is meaning of `current`. There are trands in twi, currently popular tags/words, but what is current tag is not clear to me. Guess you meant `current tweets fo a tag` instead of `current tag tweets` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [Twitter REST API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1)? Particulary, you can use [search tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets) endpoint. There are some limitations though, enforced by Twitter.

You can use one of many available [python libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries#python).

For example, some sample code for tweepy can be [found here](http://www.nirg.net/blog/2013/04/using-tweepy/).